# ¿Cómo puedo crear una lista de diccionario a partir de dos listas en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear una lista de diccionarios a partir de dos listas en python, el código de ejemplo que estoy usando es este:

```
Iden = ['a', 'b']
Sec = ['ATGC', 'TCGA']
Dict = dict.fromkeys(Iden, Sec)
print (Dict)
```

Cuando imprimo dict lo que obtengo es:

`{'a':['ATGC', 'TCGA'],'b': ['ATGC', 'TCGA']}`

El resultado que espero es:

`[{'a':['ATGC']} ,{'b': ['TCGA']}]`

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#zip) para crear una lista que combine ambas. Luego pasas el resultado al [constructor de diccionarios](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) y él se encarga:

```py
iden = ['a', 'b']
sec = ['ATGC', 'TCGA']
dic = dict(zip(iden, sec))
```

**Edición:**

Como indican en otras respuestas, mi código no devuelve: `[{'a': ['ATGC']}, {'b': ['TCGA']}]` (una lista de diccionarios), que es lo que el OP esperaba. Sin embargo, mi respuesta ha sido aceptada, así que no voy a borrar el código de arriba.

Pero para obtener ese resultado, sería así:

```py
iden = ['a', 'b']
sec = ['ATGC', 'TCGA']
dic = [ { clave: [ valor ] } for clave, valor in zip(iden, sec) ]
```

Comment: Estupendo. Borro mi respuesta para evitar duplicidades.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas si la salida es: `[{'a':['ATGC']} ,{'b': ['TCGA']}]`
podrías hacerlo algo así:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
iden = ['a', 'b']#primera lista
sec = ['ATGC', 'TCGA']#segunda lista
lista=[]#creamos una lista donde iran las lista con diccionario
def define_lista(n):#definimos la función con n como argumento que será el indice de cada lista
  while n<len(iden):#condicional donde se haga mientras que el índice no supere la longitud de la lista
    m={}#definimos un diccionario
    m[iden[n]]=[sec[n]]#rellenamos el diccionario como se pide utilizando el argumento como el índice de las listas como dijomos arriba
    lista.append(m)#vamos adjuntandolo a la lista final
    n+=1#subímos el indice para avanzar por la lista
  return lista
```

Comment: esta opción también es buena pero una regla de Python: *escribe menos siempre que sea posible*, Igual es bueno tener varias respuestas :D